# LDAP not finding user when user on a different domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

Firstly, I am new to AD / LDAP etc so this might be something obvious (I do hope so?!) and apologise if my terminology is not right, please correct me.

We have two domains, **BUSINESS** (being a Global Group) and **AUTH** (being a Domain Local Group) with one way trust between them (AUTH trusts BUSINESS).

The following code works on **MachineA** sitting on BUSINESS domain when `string LDAPServer = "BUSINESS"`.

But when run on **MachineB** sitting on AUTH domain with `string LDAPServer = "AUTH"`, it shows the message **2f. User Not Found** as the user returned in Step 2 is `NULL`. If I change `string LDAPServer = "BUSINESS"` then an exception is thrown in Step 1 that the domain controller cannot be found.

As a note the fact that `LDAPServiceAccount` can be a BUSINESS user shows that AUTH can see BUSINESS. If I change this to `LDAPServiceAccount = "BUSINESS\\NotRealName"` then Step 1 throws an exception with invalid credentials. This suggests it has resolved the BUSINESS domain user to authenticate the call? If I change `LDAPServiceAccount = "AUTH\\ValidAccount"` I get the same issue of `User == NULL` and so **2f. User Not Found**.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Who are we looking for?
            string userName = "BUSINESS\\User.Name";

            // Where are we looking?
            string LDAPServer = "AUTH";
            string LDAPServiceAccount = "BUSINESS\\InternalServiceAccountName";
            string LDAPServiceAccountPassword = "CorrespondingPassword";

            Console.WriteLine("1. Connecting to: " + LDAPServer);
            using (PrincipalContext adPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, LDAPServer, LDAPServiceAccount, LDAPServiceAccountPassword))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2. Finding: " + userName);

                using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adPrincipalContext, userName))
                {
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("2f. User Not Found!");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("3. Getting groups...");

                    using (var groups = user.GetGroups())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("4. The groups are:");
                        foreach (Principal group in groups)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", group.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("END.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this is an issue between the two AD Servers where the AUTH is not checking with BUSINESS but checking if the user exists on its configuration? Do I need to setup my LDAPServiceAccount user to have any special permissions? Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that user that is in **Business Domain** is also exist in **Auth Domain?, up to my understanding i guess you have two domains ** Business** and **Auth**.

Comment: The user **User.Name** exists in the **BUSINESS** domain but not in the **AUTH** domain which is why I think it is looking at **AUTH** rather than looking in **BUSINESS** even though I have passed username in as **BUSINESS\User.Name**?

Comment: that is the issue, the user which you are using to authentication against the domain server should exist in that particular domain or else they should have trust between each other.

Comment: I believe they do have trust between each as shown by the **LDAPServiceAccount = "BUSINESS\\InternalServiceAccountName"**. If I change this to **LDAPServiceAccount = "BUSINESS\\NotRealName"** then STEP 1 throws an exception with invalid credentials. This suggests it has resolved the BUSINESS domain user to authenticate the call?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check pre-conditions while communicating with the AD server

(1) Your machine should be on the same domain to which you are communicating.

(2) Username and Password which you passed in query should exist on that AD server.

(3) In case you are updating records, then the credential you have passed to the server should have Admin rights.

Please check these points once.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you but let me clarify (updated my question too), machine A on BUSINESS works when LDAPServer = "BUSINESS". Machine B on AUTH does not work when LDAPServer = "AUTH", user not found or LDAPServer = "BUSINESS" with domain controller not found. I need to get it working on machine B.

Comment: When your machine is on Auth domain, what are you giving in **LDAPServer**?

Comment: When Machine in AUTH domain I am setting LDAPServer = "AUTH". I've updated my question to expand on the various scenarios I've tried such as setting it to BUSINESS etc.

Comment: and what credential you are passing?

Comment: The same **BUSINESS\\InternalServiceAccountName**

Comment: why you are passing credentials of business domain when you are communicating with Auth domain, i think they don't exist in Auth domain, Am I right?

Comment: I've tried passing a user that exists in the **AUTH** domain but I get the same issue (User not found at step 2). Updated question to show that.